# Android Zip Files

Tags: java, android, file, zip

I have tried searching for answers, but can't found any, so I am posting. I am trying to zip files and by following [this link](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-programmatically-zip-and-unzip-file-in-android), I was able to do so. Problem is, with this example, file names and file paths are hard coded. So I tried to change the code base on what I need.

Original Code:

```
   // .... additional codes here  
   String inputPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/TextFiles/";
   String inputFile = "MyZippedFiles.zip";


   ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_zip))
   .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // declare an array for storing the files i.e the path of your source files
                s[0] = inputPath + "/01.txt";
                s[1] = inputPath + "/02.txt";

                /** 
                 * first parameter is the files, second parameter is zip file name 
                 * then call the zip function
                 */
                ZipManager zipManager = new ZipManager();
                zipManager.zip(s, inputPath + inputFile);
            }
        });
```

The ZipManager.java:

```
public class ZipManager {
    private static final int BUFFER = 80000;

    public void zip(String[] _files, String zipFileName) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream origin = null;
            FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(zipFileName);
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    dest));
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

            for (int i = 0; i < _files.length; i++) {
                Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]);
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]);
                origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                out.putNextEntry(entry);
                int count;

                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                origin.close();
            }

            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Again, this code is working great, but the file names are being hardcoded. So, I changed the code to fix the my issue.

New Code:

```
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_zip))
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // declare an array for storing the files i.e the path of your source files
                String[] s = dir.list(txtFilter);

                for (String filename : s) {
                    String path = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename;
                    Log.v("TEST", path);
                    ZipManager zipManager = new ZipManager();
                    zipManager.zip(path, inputPath + inputFile);
                }
            }
        });

//FilefilterName method :
public FilenameFilter txtFilter = new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            return filename.endsWith(".txt") || filename.endsWith(".TXT");
        }
    };
```

ZipManager.java:

```
public class ZipManager {

    private static final int BUFFER = 80000;

    public void zip(String path, String zipFileName) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream origin = null;
            FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(zipFileName);
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

            for (int i = 0; i < path.length(); i++) {
                Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + path);
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(path);
                origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                out.putNextEntry(entry);
                int count;

                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                origin.close();
            }

            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

LOGCAT:

```
       TEST          /storage/sdcard/TextFiles/01.txt
       Compress      Adding: /storage/sdcard/TextFiles/01.txt
       TEST          /storage/sdcard/TextFiles/02.txt
       Compress      Adding: /storage/sdcard/TextFiles/02.txt
```

**PROBLEM:**

It is creating the compressed file MyZippedFiles.zip, the problem is, it contains nothing. File size is 0. What should be done? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a simple code which create zip file of selectedFiles

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

                File zipFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "zipImages.zip");

                try {

                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
                    zipFiles(imageFiles, fileOutputStream);
                    //Do whatever you want to do with zipFile
                     //for example
                     sendZipfile(zipFile);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
public void zipFiles(List<File> fileList, OutputStream os) throws IOException {

    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); ++i) {
            File file = fileList.get(i);
            String filename = file.getName();

            byte[] bytes = readFile(file);
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
            zos.putNextEntry(entry);
            zos.write(bytes);
            zos.closeEntry();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        zos.close();
    }
}

public static byte[] readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    // Open file
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    try {
        // Get and check length
        long longlength = f.length();
        int length = (int) longlength;
        if (length != longlength)
            throw new IOException("File size >= 2 GB");
        // Read file and return data
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        f.readFully(data);
        return data;
    } finally {
        f.close();
    }
}
```